# Tkinter (TTK) - How can I change the border color for the TreeView widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I tried to change the default treeview border color using the `highlightbackground` option but it didn't work (my OS is Windows 10). here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

parent=Tk()

style=ttk.Style()
style.configure("Treeview", highlightbackground="#red") # it doesn't work!!

TreeView = ttk.Treeview(parent)
TreeView.pack()

parent.mainloop()
```

How can I reach my goal?

Comment: According to document for [ttk::Treeview](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm#M82), `highlightbackground` cannot be modified.  Also `"#red"` is not a valid color, should be `"red"` instead.

Comment: at least, is it possible to delete it (the border I mean)? in this way I could put the treeview widget in a custom frame.

Comment: You can try using other theme like `default` and set `borderwidth=0`,

Comment: What does *bordercolor* mean. I dont understand. can you show me a picture?

Comment: @acw1668 how can I change the tkinter theme? however, I used a workaround to solve it. first, I put the tree widget in a frame with a custom border as I like. second, I put other widgets to hide the original border. I used a scrolled bar for the right side, and white frames for the other ones. all of them are placed in a grid, so I don't see the original border even if I change the size of the main frame. from my point of view it's not a good solution, but it works. it's because of Tkinter lacks if we are forced to write this kind of codes..

Comment: `s = ttk.Style()` and then `s.theme_use("default")`.